# フラグメントで複数のlistviewが使用しできません

Tags: android

フラグメントで複数のlistviewを使用しようとするとエラーが出てうまく動きません。
listviewのidは"@id/android:list"でないといけないと言われます。
listfragmentをextendsしたクラスで複数のlistviewを使用することはできるのでしょうか？

Comment: 「できます」としか答えられないので、何がしたいのか、extendsしたクラスのコードなど具体的にお願いします

Answer (score -1):

面倒なのでふつうのFragmentにListViewを二つ配置する方法をお勧めします。

["ListFragment multiple lists"検索結果](https://www.google.co.jp/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=listfragment%20multiple%20lists) すぐには見つからなさそうというか、ListFragmentを二つ使うのはわかりますけど、ListFragmentの中で2つのListを保持するのというのはLis‌​tFragmentの利用想定にはないだろうと考えます。 – 272shin16 21時間前

Comment: ["ListFragment multiple lists"検索結果](https://www.google.co.jp/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=listfragment%20multiple%20lists)
すぐには見つからなさそうというか、ListFragmentを二つ使うのはわかりますけど、ListFragmentの中で2つのListを保持するのというのはListFragmentの利用想定にはないだろうと考えます。